# Understanding the below code

Tags: java, selenium

I couldn't understand this piece of code, are they defining the constructor inside a method? I understand a WebElement object is being returned, but what kind of coding concept is this in java.

```
WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function() {

     public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {

         return driver.findElement( By.id("foo") );

     }

});
```

Comment: its call making an anonymous class

Comment: have a look https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait();
```

WebDriverWait.util which extends from FluentWait, defined like this

```
public <V> V until(Function<? super T, V> isTrue)
```

So for now you know that you must pass a Function type to until. But Function is just a interface which has a unimplemented method 'apply', so you must implement it then you can use anonymous class.

Actually if you use this pattern in Selenium-Webdriver, following is a good way with generic

```
ExpectedCondition ec = new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
   public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.findElement(By.id("cutome"));
    }
  };
```

ExpectedCondition : `public interface ExpectedCondition<T> extends Function<WebDriver, T> {}`

Answer (score 0):

It is not creating a constructor. Instead, it is creating a type that is compatible with `Function`. Why is it doing so? `Function` is a interface or an abstract class (I don't really know, edit my answer) which means, it doesn't have a constructor / its constructor cannot be called. So how can you write

```
new Function ()
```

?

That is where the stuff in the curly braces comes in. `Function` has a method called `apply` and it has no implementation (abstract). This is also a reason why you can't construct abstract classes and interfaces. So now in the curly braces, you implement the `apply` method in an anonymous class that extends `Function` / implements `Function` (depending on whether `Function` is an interface or an abstract class). But Java does all these for you so you don't need to worry. The link in the above comment is quite good. You can learn more there.